# Is it possible to detect the class that called super() in base class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to detect which class called super() in the base class?
I have a base class which will be extended by several classes. In the base class constructor, i need to make an initialization based on the class which called super().

Currently I'm passing an argument while calling super(), and initializing accordingly in the base class.

```js
class BaseClass {
  constructor(child) {
    if (child === "ChildClass") {
      // ......
    }
    else {
      // .......
    }
  }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
  constructor() {
    super("ChildClass")
  }
}
```

What is the proper way of achieving this?

Thanks.

Comment: umm.. that kinda defeats the purpose of a class, don't you think?

Comment: in `BaseClass` use `this.constructor.name`.  It does seem like potentially the wrong approach though, especially in the constructor

Comment: Normally you should do the `ChildClass` specific stuff in the `ChildClass` constructor. If there is some common logic across all classes inheriting from `BaseClass` you can still call `super()`.

Comment: "*i need to make an initialization based on the class which called `super()`.*" - then something is really wrong with your design

Comment: add an `init` function to your base. call it from your `BaseClass` constructor. override it in `ChildClass`.

Comment: @Bergi I agree. This is not a good design, only an experiment.